# Troubles with adding video provider to Video Embed Field module

Tags: 8

I have installed [Video Embed Field module](https://www.drupal.org/project/video_embed_field), youtube links works good. Next I have installed [Video Embed Wistia](https://www.drupal.org/project/video_embed_wistia), and can't set valid Wistia's links. The error is

> Could not find a video provider to handle the given URL.

Video embed field and Video Embed Wistia modules are on in `admin/modules`

What I have missed? Why it doesn't work?

Comment: I have the same problem with Dailymotion. Do you find a solution @Crantisz ?

Comment: @Pauleau i've found. I've posted it as answer

Comment: Thanks you, I found it too after few minutes, I wasn't in the good fields because of ECK embeded ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution, it's simple.

You need to go in the field settings of this field and find a checkboxes   with all video providers. Mark Wistia or any new provider here and it will work.

Comment: Hi there, I still have the same issue, even if providers are marked in the Field settings page. Any idea?